# Postgres information_schema using jOOQ meta

Tags: postgresql, jooq, information-schema

I am learning about jOOQ and am a complete noob. 
In an attempt to convert postgres queries to jOOQ I am having some trouble with the `information_schema`. 
I attempted to use this: https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Meta.html with no luck.

For example for a statement somewhat like this

```sql
SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables
```

I expected `DSLContext.meta().getSchemas()` to get me where I wanted but I was wrong. Is this not how InformationSchema works?

It comes out as a Schema object but unsure as to how to access it as an information_schema

Sorry, I am a complete novice at this. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm looking to get the table_names from information_schema.tables and compare against them

Answer (score 0):

You were probably just looking for [`Meta.getTables()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Meta.html#getTables())

Comment: +1 Thanks! That is what I was looking for, 
is there something similar for columns as well ?

Comment: @kan7777: Call `Table.fields()`